# Java Error on MethodName

Tags: java, methods

I was writing a sample code

```
public class SampleTest {

    public void TestMethod1{

    }

}
```

in this I am getting error for TestMethod1 - void is an invalid type for the variable TestMethod1
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete ClassBodyDeclarations

It is taking TestMethod1 as a variable, even though I want to declare this as a method.

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis `()`...

Comment: I got the answer,public void TestMethod1() solved it

Answer (score 1):

Please learn basics of Java syntax. This not a valid way to declare method:

```
public void TestMethod1{

}
```

You should be doing like this:

```
public void TestMethod1() { //Note the () here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parenthesis:

```
public class SampleTest {

    public void TestMethod1(){ //added parenthesis 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parenthesis. Change it as shown below.

```
public class SampleTest {
    public void TestMethod1(){

    }

}
```

Also note that the java coding standards suggest to use camel case for method names, so you method name should be as `testMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

The methods should accept 0 or more parameters. Hence you will need to write it as

```
public class SampleTest {

    public void TestMethod1(){

    }

}
```

But, the coding convention says the method name should start with a lower case letter. Please refer [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)